# Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundle

I'm trying to setup an existing project,
When running `bundle install`, I'm getting following error.

I've tried many possible solutions but didn't worked for me, also I've run the suggested commands, like `gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10` but didn't work for me.

```
    bipashant@bipashant-Inspiron-5537:~/sanokam$ bundle install

    Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
    Ignoring curb-0.9.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb --version 0.9.3
    Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2
    Ignoring eventmachine-1.0.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.0.3
    Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
    Ignoring ffi-1.9.8 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.8
    Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
    Ignoring gherkin-2.12.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gherkin --version 2.12.2
    Ignoring http_parser.rb-0.5.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine http_parser.rb --version 0.5.3
    Ignoring kgio-2.8.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine kgio --version 2.8.1
    Ignoring mysql2-0.3.14 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.3.14
    Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7
    Ignoring ruby-prof-0.14.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ruby-prof --version 0.14.2

    Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

### Update 1

```
bipashant@bipashant-Inspiron-5537:~/sanokam$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

And also I've a ruby version Gemfile.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.2'
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: What ruby version are you trying to use?

Comment: @bibek-sharma  Can you please provide contents of your Gemfile

Comment: @Deepak, I'm using ruby 2.1.2, I've updated my post above.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: @mlovic, not yet bro, I've set ruby 2.3.0 on gem file and deleted GemFile.lock and trying to bundle
but don't know why it is taking too much time.

Comment: Have exactly the same problem. I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I finally modified my gemfile to have `ruby "2.3.1"`, and now everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

Your Gemfile might have this line:

```
ruby '2.1.2'
```

And you are using ruby 2.3.0, so you could either:

1. switch to ruby 2.1.2 with help of rvm/rbenv/chruby
2. update your Gemfile to `ruby '2.3.0'` and `bundle install` again

Comment: Does the log still shows this: ` Your Ruby version is 2.3.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2` ?

Comment: I'm trying to use 2.1.2 and also used the 2.1.2 as default, I've updated my post.would you please have a look.

Comment: Yaa, still same issue.

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried `ruby -v` to see if you are using 2.1.2? If you are using 2.1.2, and bundler reports you are using 2.3.0, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Last question, then I might be clueless, do you also have `rbenv` or `chruby`  installed?

Comment: No, Only rvm is installed.

Comment: This is a little weird to me. I get the impression this would happen when you have different ruby management tools installed. If this still happened to you, I suggest you remove all bundled gems, gemsets and rvm. Reinstall rvm and ruby, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear. You either have to change the ruby version specified in your Gemfile, or change the ruby version you are using by doing `rvm use 2.1.2`. You can use `rvm --default use 2.1.2` to make it the default version.

Comment: If there's no particular reason to to use version `2.1.2` however, you'd probably be better off using `2.3.0`. You can do that by editing your Gemfile to say `ruby '2.3.0'`.

Comment: I also tried this, but I got so many error, while installing bundle install .

Comment: Is it the same error? If the error is different this time, please post it here or as part of your question.